# Centering children of a div without using <center>

Tags: html, css

The `center` tag is deprecated. I should not use it anymore. However, I haven't been able to reproduce the following with using `center`:

```
<div><center><span>Test<span> <span>Test<span> <span>Test<span></center></div>
```

I have tried using `margin: 0 auto` and `align: center` but both don't work: http://jsfiddle.net/zTY4f/

Comment: Do you want to center the `<div>`, or its contents? Also, the `<span>` tags are not properly closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`margin: 0 auto` works if you explicitly set a width as well.

```
div {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer becuase you might not want to center the text within the div, just the div itself.

Comment: This is the better answer ***iff*** you want to center the div itself. If you want to center contents inside the div then @beerwin's suggestion seems more appropriate imo.

Answer (score 3):

use css:

```
div {
    text-align:center;
}
```